# How to draw on uiimage view

Tags: swift

I managed to draw on uiview and I tried to draw on uiimage view using same method but didn't work at all please help

```
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    
    
    
    
    lines.forEach { (line) in
        context.setStrokeColor(line.color.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(CGFloat(line.strokeWidth))
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        for (i, p) in line.points.enumerated() {
            if i == 0 {
                context.move(to: p)
            } else {
                context.addLine(to: p)
            }
        }
        context.strokePath()
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is my canvas code. I tried to change the uiview to UIImageViews but didn't work at all.

```
  class Canvas: UIView {
      // public function
      fileprivate var strokeColor = UIColor.black
      fileprivate var strokeWidth: Float = 1


      fileprivate var lines = [Line]()
```

Drew method
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
super.draw(rect)

```
      guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {      return } 
    
    lines.forEach { (line) in
        context.setStrokeColor(line.color.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(CGFloat(line.strokeWidth))
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        for (i, p) in line.points.enumerated() {
            if i == 0 {
                context.move(to: p)
            } else {
                context.addLine(to: p)
            }
        }
        context.strokePath()
    }
    
    
    
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    lines.append(Line.init(strokeWidth: strokeWidth, color: strokeColor, points: []))
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else { return }
    guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else { return }
    lastLine.points.append(point)
    lines.append(lastLine)
    setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of using Image view, how about adding an image to the background of your View? Also, paste your canvas code if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2):

> **Do not use image views for custom drawing.** The UIImageView class does
> not draw its content using the draw(_:) method. Use image views only
> to present images. To do custom drawing involving images, subclass
> UIView directly and draw your image there.

If your image is static to the background of your canvas view, you can use **patternImage** to your canvas view as the background color.

Example of code called from ViewController:

```
// signatureView is a Canvas and set image as a background
        if let img = UIImage(named: "bg.png") {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(signatureView.frame.size)
            img.draw(in: signatureView.bounds)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            if let image = image {
                signatureView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
            }
        }
```

Another solution is to use an Image property in your canvas class and draw an image inside your canvas class's Draw method as below:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        self.image?.draw(in: self.bounds)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
```

Now you can still use an UIImageView but the ImageView should be the **subview of a Canvas View**, In that case (Assume UIImageView already have a image) call like bellow:

```
// sign2ImageView as a sub view of Canvas
        sign2ImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        if let img = sign2ImageView.image { //or UIImage(named: "codinginswiftpanel")
            sign2ImageView.image = nil
            sign2ImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
            signatureView2.image = img
        }
```

Here is the output: 1st one is the background of UIView(Canvas) and the second one marked orange is an UIImageView which is a subview of the modified Canvas View.

[image]